# jQuery DataTables plugin: server-side filter for input and select in specific columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

With the jQuery DataTables plugin, I've got the sorting down for server-side.

My problem now is how to filter a few specific columns server-side. Some columns I want to be filtered via `<input>`, and some columns I want to filter via `<select>`.

The documentation has separate examples of input filtering and then select filtering where it loops through *all* columns, but not a combination thereof.
I've seen this question, but it hasn't helped. 
[DataTables Server Side Individual Column Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492388/datatables-server-side-individual-column-filtering)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue so i worked out to be like below,

```html
var tableColumns = [
                    { "data": "adcampaignName", "name": "Adcampaign Name","search" : true},
                    { "data": "advertiser.name", "name": "Advertiser Name","search" : true },
                    { "data": "offerName", "name": "Offer Name","search" : true },
                    { "data": "dailyBudget", "name": "Daily Budget","search" : false},
                    { "data": "startingOn", "name": "Starting On","search" : false },
                    { "data": "endingOn", "name": "Ending On","search" : false },
                    { "data": "status", "name": 'Status',"search" : true,"dropdown" : true  }
            ];
```

In places like columns of datatables have used the tablecolumns variable.

Additionally used the same to add/not to add on select/textfield filter i used conditions like

```html
if(tableColumns[index].search && !tableColumns[index].dropdown){
```

see below, In initComplete,

```html
$('#example').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "columns": tableColumns,
            "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( {
                url: '/test.json',
                pages: 5, // number of pages to cache
              "type": "POST"
            } ),
            
       initComplete: function () {
             this.api().columns().every( function (index) {
             var column = this;
                if(tableColumns[index].search && tableColumns[index].dropdown){
                 var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                     .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                     .on( 'change', function () {
                         var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                             $(this).val()
                         );
  
                         column
                             .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                             .draw();
                     } );
  
                 //column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                     select.append( '<option value="active">Active</option>' )
                     select.append( '<option value="inactive">InActive</option>' )
                 //} );
                }
            } );
         }
        } );
    
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
      $('#example tfoot th').each( function (index) {
       if(tableColumns[index].search && !tableColumns[index].dropdown){
           var title = $(this).text();
           $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
       }
      } );
   
      // DataTable
      var table = $('#example').DataTable();
   
      // Apply the search
      table.columns().every( function (index) {
          var that = this;
          if(tableColumns[index].search && !tableColumns[index].dropdown){
           $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
               if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                   that
                       .search( this.value )
                       .draw();
               }
           } );
          }
      } );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that Column Filtering add-on for DataTables is what you need. See http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html

Comment: I ended up doing something described here. http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=3931&page=1

Comment: @mg1075 The link is broken

Comment: @Jérôme - The datatables forum link has probably changed to this: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/3931/